# Redirect based on URL

Tags: html, .htaccess, redirect

I'm not sure of the most efficient way to redirect based on the URL. I've seen examples of htaccess that are close to what I need but I don't understand the programming behind it at all. Here's what I need to happen:

1. Check if page is "watch.html".
2. Redirect if URL appears as "watch?blahblah" instead of "watch.html?blahblah".

   - Basically if URL doesn't have the .html
3. Redirect to same page with .html added into it.

Any help writing this code is appreciated.

Comment: Which part of what don't you understand? Give what you're working with or what you have tried. Otherwise, I don't know there's a question here.

Comment: I've just been looking through forums at different htaccess codes that examine the URL and redirect based upon it and I've realized that I can't understand the way that htaccess is coded. So I've defaulted to asking if anyone here knows how to do what I need.

Comment: There are lots of tutorials for this out there ([like this one](http://expressionengine.com/wiki/Remove_index.php_From_URLs/)), and I'm sure there are other questions on SO that cover all or most of this topic. Your specific requirements notwithstanding, keep in mind this isn't a code request site, and you need a concrete question to answer. See the [FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/faq).

Comment: I just hoped someone could save me the 4 hours of research and endless testing.

Comment: Welcome to programming! Just think, the next time it'll only take three hours and 44 minutes to accomplish the same thing. But then, the possibilities... (Of course I'm being facetious, next attempt three hours, tops.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Nah, I think it's perfectly okay. The mod_rewrite module has a fairly obscure syntax, and it can be very frustrating.

The thing you want could be written like this:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !\.html$
RewriteRule (.*) $1.html
```

First we turn the rewrite engine on. Then there's the [RewriteCond](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewritecond) directive: if that condition evaulates to true, a single RewriteRule following it will be applied. The syntax of RewriteCond is straightforward: `RewriteCond <subject> <regex pattern>`; the condition will evaulate to true if the pattern matches the subject. In our case the pattern is the server variable called REQUEST_URI, which may be familiar to you from PHP, it holds the URI the user requested. The pattern here is the regex `\.html$`. The \ here is an escape character to escape the dot, which as you may know has a special meaning in regex ("match any character"); the $ sign signifies the end of line; the ! negates the whole expression, so the condition will be true if the pattern following it doesn't match. So, the RewriteCond line says: "If the requested URI does not end with the string .html".

Then comes the [RewriteRule](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewriterule) directive. Its syntax is `RewriteCond <from> <to> [optional flags]`. The 'from' part is a regex pattern to be matched. The 'to' part is a string to which we will rewrite the original query. In our specific example the from is `(.*)`: the . means "any character", the star means "any times", so we're basically saying "any number of any characters", meaning we'd like to capture the entire path. We put it in paranthesis to enable us to refer to the captured part later. Then we rewrite this into: `$1.html`, where $1 refers to first string we captured in the "from" part.

And that's it: when we write "example.com/something" in the address bar, the page "example.com/something.html" will be served.

Of course this is very basic, and it could be improved a lot to be more elegant and stuff, but this should get you started. There are a lot of helpful tutorials around, and the docs are also very helpful.

Comment: @Alex You're welcome. Make sure to actually learn from it, otherwise Jared will be right, and you'll be just a script kiddie :p.

Comment: I don't think that @AlexBath is script kiddie (which is a misappropriation of that term in this case). However, there is a lot of heavy lifting involved in actually learning how to do a lot of application techniques, but the *effort is where the payoff lies*. It's a positive feedback loop, but you have to make the effort. Yes, the Apache modules can be frustrating to learn about due to wonky documentation and complexity inherent to it's purpose, but you gotta learn sometime. Good work on the basic explanation.